# Compile Error with typedef and std

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio C++ 2010.

I have a Header file, GNode.h, a snippit below:

```
#ifndef GNODE_H
#define GNODE_H
#include <vector>

typedef vector<int> ADJNODE_LIST;
```

I will get an error on the `Error: vector is not a template` on the 2nd line `vector`

However, when I add `std::` to `vector` as such:

```
typedef std::vector<int> ADJNODE_LIST;
```

there is no compile error.

It seems that it cannot find the `<vector>` library.

Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because vector lives in the `std` namespace.

You can think of it as having been defined as:

```
namespace std {
    template<typename T, ...>
    class vector {
        ...
    };
}
```

The file you include is called `vector`, however to access the type you need to qualify it with it's namespace, so `std::vector<int>`, where `::` is the scoping operator.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing. It almost sounds like you're suggesting to wrap the code in `namespace std {...}`...

Answer (score -5):

it can, but it is surrounded by something called namespace.

outside the namespace (e.g your program) you don't have access to the elements inside namespace

you can use

```
using namespace std;
```

or prepend everything inside std namespace with `std::`

Comment: No, do NOT encourage people to drag in the entirety of namespace std in a header. It's bad practise

Comment: still an option, and the easiest!

Comment: @arashkordi tell me how in the world it is easier than prepending everything with `std::`. (In fact, `std::` is much easier due to terrible naming conflicts you get (and deserve) when you do `using namespace std;`.)

Comment: It's the most short sited option you could make. It is a terrible thing to tell people to do. Understanding the way namespaces can be harnessed to control scope is very important, and telling people they can just remove such a feature is a crime

Comment: I agree with Tony The Lion - it's very bad practice to insert "using namespace xxx;" into a header file - it risks name collisions for anyone who uses your header.

Comment: oh, I like that namespace :D

Comment: that's absurd. you guys are killing me i have worked with codes (legacy code, not my work) with hundreds of thousands of lines with 'using namespace std' every where and not a single conflict with std. seriously, show me a professional developers who names a variable string or vector or map

Comment: It's not just a case of 'std', it applies to any namespace. If your header 'uses' a namespace, anything that uses your header is also using that namespace, with out any clear indication. besides, vector is also used for maths, map potentially for a game, string for physics system.

Comment: @arashkordi are you seriously telling me that someone, even if they know all the names in the `std::` namespace defined in C++98, would have known all the ones that would be introduced in C++11, and know all the names that will come in the future? Namespaces exist for good reasons.

Comment: @juanchopanza: so does 'using namespace'

Comment: @arashkordi No good reasons for it. But if you want carry on with your bad practices, that's fine.

Comment: @Zoidberg no need for insult